# Sockets on Google App Engine

Tags: php, sockets, google-app-engine, websocket, ratchet

I have sockets working on my localhost sever, however I want to migrate to google app engine. There isn't any exact documentation on the matter. I am currently connecting on my localhost port 8080 how can I put on my app engine server

Here is my Ratchet/Php code

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
$server->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question exactly what you mean by "sockets" or whether you're using App Engine Standard or Flex. Assuming you're using Standard:

- Websockets are not currently supported by App Engine
- Inbound sockets (e.g. `ServerSocket` in Java) are also not supported
- Outbound sockets are supported, but are in beta and have some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/)

8080 is the default port used by the dev server for normal inbound HTTP connections (for Java at least). Deployed apps just use 80 (which means you can omit the port since 80 is the default for HTTP traffic) (or https/443 for TLS).